# Creating a distribution which will become uniform after applying to it a given function $f$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I have some real valued function $f:[a, b]\to [c, d]$ for which I have no analytic closed form, but can easily calculate $f(x)$ for any $x\in [a, b]$ ($f$ is not smooth or even continuous on much of its domain).

I want to find some distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over $[a, b]$, s.t. if $X\sim \mathcal{D}$  then $f(X)\sim\text{Uni}\left[c,d\right]$ or, more realistically, approximately uniformly over some discretization (binning) of $[c, d]$.

I thought of starting with $\mathcal{D}_0= \text{Uni}\left[a,b\right]$ (discrete, and can later be smoothed) and iteratively refining $\mathcal{D}_{i+1}$ by sampling from $\mathcal{D}_i$, applying $f$ to the sample, and then lowering the probability of bins which ended up in target-bins with higher count than the median count and vice versa.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: The obvious way is to generate a uniform distribution on $[c, d]$, and then apply $f^{-1}$ to it. Even if $f$ is not injective and $f^{-1}(y)$ is a set instead of a point, you can just choose one of the points of this set as the ant-image of $y$. Is it not possible to do this?

Comment: @wimi The only way I have of computing $f^{-1}\left(y\right)$ is by direct search over $[a,b]$ for the $x$ whose image is nearest to $y$. For a fine resolution discretization of both domains this becomes rather expensive pretty fast (quadratic in the number of bins).